# ORA-01779 on Join Update

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

I'm developing a web application on vb.net with Oracle as DB and I'm having some problems to update a table by using joins.

Since I'm kind of a newbie on Oracle, I can't make my query go on...i've been reading and I knew that oracle doesn't supports Joins on UPDATE, so i searched for alternatives and I finished on this:

```
UPDATE (SELECT pda.id_propuesta
          FROM abd_prop_det_archivos pda
         INNER JOIN abd_participantes_invitados pi
            ON (pda.id_solicitud = pi.id_solicitud)
           AND pi.id_solicitud = :id_solicitud
           AND pi.rut = :rut)
SET id_propuesta = :id_propuesta
```

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you want a `WHERE EXISTS` clause

```
UPDATE abd_prop_det_archivos pda 
   SET ID_PROPUESTA = :ID_PROPUESTA
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM ABD_PARTICIPANTES_INVITADOS pi
                WHERE pda.id_solicitud = pi.id_solicitud) 
                  AND pi.id_solicitud = :id_solicitud
                  AND PI.RUT = :RUT )
```